# (Bottle) How to yield template in place of previous string

Tags: python, bottle

I a have route that does some calculations that may take some time to finish. I am trying to send to the user some notes on the progress of this calculation before the route returns the template with results.

Basically, I am using gevent to yield a string of text into an iframe when the calculation has reached a certain phase. At the end I would like to yield a Bottle template into an iframe, but at the same time delete all strings that were sent before the last yield.

Does anyone have an idea how to do this the right way?I tried doing it by yielding a short javascript `document.body.innerHTML=""` just before yielding a template, but this doesn't work.

```
from gevent import monkey; monkey.patch_all()
from time import sleep
from bottle import route, run

@route('/stream')
def stream():
    yield 'START'
    sleep(3)  # some calculation goes here
    yield template("send_results")

run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080, server='gevent')
```

Answer (score 0):

Yielding a script tag runs the script in the open window.  Here is an example of it working. Also don't use bottle's gevent server module, use this instead.

```
from gevent import monkey; monkey.patch_all()
from gevent.pywsgi import WSGIServer
from time import sleep
import bottle
from bottle import route, template

@route('/stream')
def stream():
    yield '<h3 id="firstid">Starting</h3>'
    sleep(3)  # some calculation goes here
    yield '<script>document.getElementById("firstid").innerHTML = "Hello World";</script>'

botapp = bottle.app()
server = WSGIServer(("0.0.0.0", int(80)), botapp)
server.serve_forever()
```